# How to scroll down programmatically a view opened by a push notification?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, push-notification, chat

When I open the chat view of my app I manage to scroll the table view down programmatically from the `func viewDidAppear()`.

However, when I open this view from a push notification, the app does not scroll down the table view programmatically.

Do you have any clue about the way to fix it?

I have already tried to use `viewDidLoad()` and `viewWillAppear()`.

Here's my code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

     // Scroll down when view opens


        let numberOfSections = self.ConvertationTableView.numberOfSections

        let numberOfMessages = self.messageArray.count

        func numberOfMessageCheck(){

            if numberOfMessages < 1 {

            }
            else {


                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: numberOfMessages-1 , section: numberOfSections-1)
                self.ConvertationTableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .middle, animated: false)}

        }


        numberOfMessageCheck()


    }
```

In `override func viewDidLoad()` I call the function `retrieveMessages()`. I wonder if my issue is related to that. Here's the code of `retrieveMessages()`:

```
 func retrieveMessages(){

        let messagesDB = self.ref?.child("conversation").child(finalGroup)

        messagesDB?.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String,String>

            let text = snapshotValue["MessageBody"]!

            let message = Message()
            message.messageBody = text
            message.name =  snapshotValue["name"]!
            message.sender = snapshotValue["sender"]!

            self.messageArray.append(message)

            self.configureTableView()
            self.ConvertationTableView.reloadData()


        })

    }
```

Comment: When you reload your table, you need to scroll to bottom or top. Please, give a try on that. Get the latest result of your array, then scroll to that index.

Comment: I tried what you said, but now the view is scolling to the bottom each time that someone is posting on the group chat. I would prefer to only scroll down once, when we open the the chat view.

Comment: Do that, check if is the only time you want, and scroll only that time